# 3D partial dependence plot from h2o model

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

I aim to create a [partial dependence plot (PDP)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_partial_dependence.html) which shows the interaction of two input variables on the response for my h2o random forest model. Here is a reproducible setup of an example situation:

```
library(h2o)
data(diabetes, package = 'lars')

h2o.init()

train_data <- as.h2o(cbind(diabetes$x, target=diabetes$y))
X_names <- colnames(diabetes$x)
y_name  <- "target"

rf <- h2o.randomForest(x=X_names, y=y_name, training_frame=train_data,
                       ntrees=10, max_depth=5)

h2o.partialPlot(rf, train_data, c("age", "bmi"))
```

The code above plots two PDPs separately for `age` and `bmi`, but it doesn't show anything about how they affect the response when they vary together.

Say I instead want to plot `age` in the x axis, `bmi` in the y axis, and the mean response in the z axis in a 3-dimensional plot.

Is there a functionality (or a good-practice guideline) in h2o that helps build plots like this? I can work my way around by creating the response data myself, but that can get a bit cumbersome.

See related:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197455/how-to-plot-3d-partial-dependence-in-gbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a feature of `h2o.partialPlot`. You can verify that in the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia5qi51ZTcAhVGhOAKHSNrCTgQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rdocumentation.org%2Fpackages%2Fh2o%2Ftopics%2Fh2o.partialPlot&usg=AOvVaw2j0eLGpCNopk-OPxOFiThp) and the [source code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_misc/runit_partialPlot.R).

I think your options include

1. [Requesting](https://github.com/h2o/h2o/issues) that as a feature
2. Using the approach you linked which will work fine with your `h2o` data after you change it back to a regular R class

Comment: Yes it does seem like the case. I wanted to open a thread just in case anyone had another solution, but seems like this is it. I'm accepting your answer, thanks for the input! (Could you edit the link from `h2o` to `h2oai`?  `h2o` is another project on GitHub.)